# How do I emulate su's behavior with sudo?

Tags: sudo, su

I'm trying to make sudo ask for target password, except when run by `root`. Here's what I do:

```
Defaults:!root    targetpw
```

This way it asks for my password, and if I make it like this:

```
Defaults:yuri    targetpw
```

it asks for target user's password, but that's not what I wanted.

Comment: Doesn't just `Defaults targetpw` do the job?

Comment: @Mikel Well, it appears yes, but I wonder what's wrong with `Defaults:!root`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you can do is set `targetpw` as default, but this won't require `root` to enter any password.  You can't configure `sudo` to do this and it wouldn't make any sense, either, since `root` may always do whatever he wants (`su` doesn't ask for a password either, does it‽).

So put

```
Defaults targetpw
```

into your `/etc/sudoers` file and you should have `su` behavior.

Comment: Any clues what's wrong with `Defaults:!root`?

Comment: Tried to figure it out, but… no.

Answer (score 4):

From the `sudoers` man page:

```
An exclamation point (‘!’) can be used as a logical not operator in a list or
alias as well as in front of a Cmnd.  This allows one to exclude certain values.
For the ‘!’ operator to be effective, there must be something for it to exclude.
For example, to match all users except for root one would use:

     ALL,!root

 If the ALL, is omitted, as in:

     !root

 it would explicitly deny root but not match any other users.  This is different
 from a true “negation” operator.
```

So,

```
Defaults:ALL,!root    targetpw
```

should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that's the only thing that made me uncomfortable about the issue, but I accepted `Andreas Wiese`'s answer, because it seems more like it for the task.